# Manhua where the protagonist in red dragon-like armor is the last to return to his original world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is in this red dragon-like armor. No one knows this, but when you die you return to the original world with all your abilities.

The main character was the last to return, after 15 years, when he finally makes it to the final boss and dies trying to fight him. When he returns to the original world, he soon conquers a succubus mansion, and reunites with the queen that was his ally in the other world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I tried to clean this up a bit, but I wasn't sure what you meant by "concurs a succubus masion;" conquers? a ?? mansion?  Can you [edit] your question to clarify what you meant?  Also, when did you read this?  Can you describe any of the characters, the setting or the art (especially the cover)?

Answer (score 4):

***[The Max Level Returner](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/elq6nas/the-max-level-returner)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> The world falls into a state of panic when 120 million players of a popular VR game, Eternal World, vanish without a trace one day. A few months later, they begin returning one by one after dying in the game. But they’re not the only ones to make it back—monsters also start to appear and wreak havoc on Earth. All hope seems lost until the Masked Monarch, the most powerful player of Eternal World, returns. He quickly assembles his old team back together to defeat the beasts and the nefarious Demon King once and for all. But man-made weapons are useless against the enemies they must fight, and players are struggling to level up without the game’s special items or rewards. The Masked Monarch has a few tricks up his sleeve, but will they be enough to save the world?

It seems to include most of the plot points that you described, such as the red-armoured protagonist returning from another world after battling the Demon King, and the castle full of succubi. I'll update this answer with an expanded description a bit later, but here's a relevant image for now.

[image]

Comment: @user153032 - If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].